# Google Image Search using Google Custom Search API Daily limit exceeded error

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-custom-search

I am using [Google custom search API](https://cloud.google.com/console?redirected=true#/project/apps~drtool-diaspark-12/apiui/api/customsearch) for searching images in my windows phone 7 application,
The API Work fine after some call it stops returning results i,e. images. 
It gives me an error of Daily Limit Exceeded.
Can anyone explain how to handle this problem or is there any other API for searching Images on Google?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google custom search API is depreciated, Google has not published any documentation on its usage limits, although speculated that it is 5,000 calls, this is not an official figure, and it  makes sense that Google reduces the limit as the API nears its shelve life.

From the google API page

**Note: The Google Web Search API has been officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day will be limited. Therefore, we encourage you to move to Custom Search, which provides an alternative solution.**

I suggest you look into the Bing search API which has several examples online to get you started.

You can also look into  https://developers.google.com/custom-search/ instead